# Laravel Eloquent Query using Where, With, Where and orWhere condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to make a Laravel Eloquent query which will find me orders by order number and product name.
I have 3 tables orders, order_details & products.

**orders table**

```
id    |   user_id    |    order_id    |    order_cart_id
---------------------------------------------------------
1     |      1       |  123-456-7890  |          1
2     |      1       |  789-456-3210  |          2
```

**order_details table**

```
id    |   order_id   |    cart_id     |        p_id 
---------------------------------------------------------
1     |      1       |        1       |          22
2     |      1       |        1       |          42
3     |      1       |        1       |          2
4     |      1       |        1       |          32
5     |      1       |        1       |          423
6     |      2       |        2       |          432
```

**products table**

```
id    |    p_name
--------------------
1     |      ABC       
2     |      CAD       
42    |      PRO       
22    |      XYZ
32    |      IND    
423   |      MP
432   |      ETC
```

**Orders Model**

```
public function order_cart_products()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(\App\Models\Products\Product::class,
        \App\Models\Orders\OrderDetail::class,
        'cart_id',
        'id',
        'cart_id','p_id');
}
```

**Order Controller**

```
$orders = Order::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->where('order_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->with('order_cart_products', function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->orWhere('p_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
    })
    ->get()->toArray();
```

What I am trying to do is by searching `order_id(123-456-7890)` I need to get all its details with products in it and if I search via `p_name(ABC)`. I need to get all orders in which ABC has been listed. But I don't understand where am I going wrong am not getting desired output.

Comment: `with` does not affect the query itself. It fetches relations using secondary queries and loads them to the individual models, so that if you try to use those relations later, it'll use the ones loaded (which could be filtered) instead of running a query for that individual model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below:

```php
$orders = Order::with('order_cart_products')
    ->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('order_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhereHas('order_cart_products', function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->where('p_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            })
    })
    ->get();
```